# How to find the width of a gaussian curve?

Tags: probability

I'm revising probability again for my Machine Learning course at uni. Part of this revision involves going over gaussian distrubitions.

I'm confused as to how the width of a gaussian curve is measured. I've worked out how to calculate the position of the peak (which is the value of the mean), and the height of the peak ( $\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2})$

I also know that the mean controls the placement of the curve, and variance controls dispersion (i.e. the width).

I'd appreciate any insight on how to actually calculate the values of the width [image]

i.e. for the red curve with mean 0 and s.d 2, why is the width approximately from x = -6 to x = 6? Basic as possible as I don't need to go into a whole lot of detail.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no actual finite width; the "width" is only relative to a probability "tolerance" that you consider to be negligible. For instance if a probability of less than $0.005$ is negligible for your purposes, then you can treat the width as being 6 standard deviations (3 to the left of the mean and 3 to the right of the mean). That's because the probability of deviating by more than 3 standard deviations is less than 0.005.

Comment: Should have added, I know the width isn't actually finite (i.e. the curve never actually touches the x axis), I'd just like a method for roughly guessing how to draw a curve by hand given parameters  mu and sigma^2

Comment: The easiest way to draw *one* distribution is probably to draw a standard normal distribution, then replace your $x$-axis labels: replace $0$ with $\mu$, $1$ with $\mu+\sigma$, $-1$ with $\mu-\sigma$, etc.

Comment: Related question: [Defining the width of a guassian](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181413/defining-the-width-of-a-gaussian-function)

Comment: That makes sense, but when do I know how to stop (i.e. it most likely won't be feasible to go up to mu - 500sigma (I should really learn how to format correctly...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normally distributed random variable will be within 3 standard deviations of the mean 99.7% of the time, therefore the red line will approach 0 rapidly around $\pm 6$.

Comment: This makes sense (it matches with the image I posted) - lets say the mean is 3, and the s.d is 2, then the width will range from (approx.) -3 to 9 right? I know what I'm saying is technically inaccurate as the curve doesn't actually end there, it goes on infinitely, but I just want a pictorial representation of how to draw a curve with the parameters stated. What happens the other 0.3% of the time?

Comment: @F.Tahir That reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Another question while we're here if that's okay. With the scenario given, is the formula for the peak still the same (i.e. 1/sqrt(2*pi)*st.dev = 1/sqrt(2*pi)*2 = 0.199?